# I'm trying to create a code that asks the user to choose from one of the products and add the quantity that he needs but I'm stuck?

Tags: java

This is the code. I'm really struggling with it little help will be much appreciated thanks in advance!

```java
package online.market;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class OnlineMarket {
        
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.print("Products\n");

    HashMap<String, Double> products = new HashMap<>();
        
    Scanner product = new Scanner(System.in);  

    products.put("Computer", 999.99);
    products.put("Airpods", 129.30);
    products.put("TV", 129.30);
    products.put("Playstation 5", 569.70);
    System.out.println(products);

    String name = product.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Which product would you like to choose?");
}
```

Comment: you should print the question before waiting for input `product.nextLine();` you can print out the name afterwards to get an idea what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice continue your code with this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String option = s.next();
System.out.println("How much"+option+"you want?");
int q = s.nextInt();
```

Of course the String "option" is the input of the user which you expecting you can also use a loop to make sure that user will input one of your options like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String option = s.next();
while (!(option.equals("option1") || option.equals("option2"))){
        System.out.println("Wrong input please try again");
        option = s.next();
 }
System.out.println("How much"+option+"you want?");
    int q = s.nextInt();
    while (q<0){
        System.out.println("Wrong input please try again");
        q=s.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! plz consider accepting or upvoting my answer if it was helpful so community know the problem is solver or update your question for any other problems you had

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Products\n");

    HashMap<String, Double> products = new HashMap<>();

    Scanner product = new Scanner(System.in);

    products.put("Computer", 999.99);
    products.put("Airpods", 129.30);
    products.put("TV", 129.30);
    products.put("Playstation 5", 569.70);
    System.out.println(products);

    System.out.println("Which product would you like to choose?");
    String name = product.nextLine();

    Double price = products.get(name);
    if (price != null) {
        System.out.println("enter quantity :");
        int n = product.nextInt();
        System.out.println("you order " + n + " x " + name + "   , Total : "+n*price);
    } else {
        System.out.println("sorry this product not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful !

Comment: Hi @LyubomirIvailovMarkov if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would finish off your code. Its hard to tell exactly what you want it to do.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.print("Products\n");
    HashMap<String, Double> products = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner product = new Scanner(System.in);  

    products.put("Computer", 999.99);
    products.put("Airpods", 129.30);
    products.put("TV", 129.30);
    products.put("Playstation 5", 569.70);
    System.out.println(products);

    System.out.println("Which product would you like to choose?");
    String name = product.nextLine();

    System.out.println("How much would you like?");
    int count = product.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Total Cost: "+products.get(name) * count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm just trying to  ask the user to choose a product and then ask
the user to enter the quantity they require of that product